# Reorder divs after ajax call using data-attribute and using .animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

I have a list of divs with unique numeric id and data-position in order as they are (1 for the first in the list, 2 for the second ...).

After doing a ajax call through jquery, the result is a JSON call that changes the order of those id's.

each div have a button where you can mark and unmark the div on the top of this list.
if the mark button is called, the ajax calls that id with a new position (generally 1, but if there are more messages marked as important, this may be 2 or 3 but always following the position order) from his unmarked position
if the unmark button is fired, the ajax calls his new position.

so more or less the result is this one:

before ajax call:

```html
<div class="card-wrapper" style="display:block;" id="1563" data-position="1">
    message text
</div>
<div class="card-wrapper" style="display:block;" id="1561" data-position="2">
    message text
</div>
<div class="card-wrapper" style="display:block;" id="1567" data-position="3">
    message text
</div>
<div class="card-wrapper" style="display:block;" id="1568" data-position="4">
    message text
</div>
```

button is fired, ajax called:

```
if (res.response === 'ok') {
   res.order.forEach(function (value) {
       $('#' + value.id + '.card-wrapper').attr('data-position', value.position);
   });
...
}
```

after ajax call:

```html
<div class="card-wrapper" style="display:block;" id="1563" data-position="3">
    message text
</div>
<div class="card-wrapper" style="display:block;" id="1561" data-position="1">
    message text
</div>
<div class="card-wrapper" style="display:block;" id="1567" data-position="2">
    message text
</div>
<div class="card-wrapper" style="display:block;" id="1568" data-position="4">
    message text
</div>
```

now i would like to sort the divs with the new data position in order using some sort of animation (swapping them) just after the ajax has been called.

please consider that all .card-wrapper may have different height and inside of it there are different bootstrap cards.

i tried using .animate with jquery and more or less i got how it works (get the height of every div and use .animate({top: '+=x'}) or .animate({top: '-=x'}) but i can't figure out how to do it all together,

any help is appreciated.

sorry for any mispelling or typo.
if it's unclear just ask me.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understood as your requirement.  You want to rearrange the divs by data-position after ajax call completion. I could not get a great animation but could get them to order properly using jquery.  I put all the divs in another div with id called 'parent'.
Hope this helps.

```
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Div Rearrangement</h1>
                <div class="row" id="parent">
                            <div class="card-wrapper" style="display:block; height:100px; border: 1px solid yellow;" id="1568" data-position="5">
                              5  message text
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-wrapper" style="display:block; height:100px; border: 1px solid blue;" id="1563" data-position="3">
                              3  message text
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-wrapper" style="display:block; height:100px; border: 1px solid violet;" id="1561" data-position="1">
                              1  message text
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-wrapper" style="display:block; height:100px; border: 1px solid orange;" id="1568" data-position="6">
                              6  message text
                            </div>                        
                            <div class="card-wrapper" style="display:block; height:100px; border: 1px solid indigo;" id="1567" data-position="2">
                              2  message text
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-wrapper" style="display:block; height:100px; border: 1px solid green;" id="1568" data-position="4">
                              4  message text
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-wrapper" style="display:block; height:100px; border: 1px solid red;" id="1568" data-position="7">
                              7  message text
                            </div>                        

                </div>
            </div>

        <script>
                if (res.response === 'ok') {
                    var count = $("#parent > div").length;
                    console.log(count);

                    for(var i=1; i<count+1; i++) {
                        var thisDiv = $(' #parent > div[data-position=' + i + ']');
                        console.log(thisDiv);                       
                        thisDiv.appendTo($("#parent")).hide().fadeIn(1000);
                    }
                }
        </script>
```